# New vs Returning Users by sessions or pageviews

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, universal-analytics

I'm trying to guage my new vs returning user rate for a specific page.

When I set User Type against Sessions it tells me that New Users account for 75%, but then when I set User Type against pageviews it tells me that New User account for only 35%.

What is the difference between these two? and which would be better for me to use?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A user can view many pages during a session. Your new users are viewing far fewer pages than returning users. Three quarters of visits to the website are from new users, but they account for only a third of pages viewed.